# bootstrap table-responsive scroll not working on ios (direction rtl)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, drupal-7

i'm using bootsrap for a website that has an arabic and english versions. so table-responsive which is supposed to add a scroll to the table on mobile is not working on IOS. the scroll is not showing and the table is not scrolling. however when i add direction: rtl to the table-responsive class it works but messes up my design. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider posting some relevant codes for this as well...

Comment: it's just a simple html code : <div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-striped"></table></div> , it works fine on english but when the direction changes to rtl the scroll is gone on ios

Answer (score 2):

just do this :

```
.table-responsive .table {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

RTL Best Solution.Tested In All Devices

```
.table-responsive {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
direction: ltr;
}
.table-responsive > table {
direction: rtl !important;
}
table, th {
direction:rtl
}
table, tr {
direction:rtl;
}

$('.table-responsive').animate({ scrollLeft: $('.thposition1').position().left }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

just add these lines to your CSS with check priority :

```
.table-responsive {
      direction:ltr !important;
      }
.table-responsive .table {
      direction:rtl !important;
}
```

wish can helps you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `touch !important;` to your `.table-responsive` along with `max-width: none;` to the `.table-responsive .table`

```
.table-responsive {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}

.table-responsive .table {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Please add more details to this answer, code only answers can easily be misunderstood and are bad practice in general. Please update your code accordingly. Thank you.